# Delphi Webbrowser and CSS3

Tags: delphi, css, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-9

My app loads some HTML into a Webbrowser (TEmbeddedWB from [bsalsa.com](http://bsalsa.com)), and I would like to use some CSS3 features like `border-radius`. I installed Internet Explorer 9, because it supports the `border-radius` property. Okay, so just to test if the property works in a Delphi application, I make a new project with a Memo and a TEmbeddedWB. In the `Memo1OnChange` event I make the Webbrowser load whatever text is in the memo. I then type the following text into the memo:

```
<div style="background-color:green;  border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width:200px; height:200px;"></div>
```

And the webbrowser displays the green box, but there are no border-radii! I then try to save it to a file, and load it up in IE9, and the border-radii are clearly visible.

I have also set the Registry Key `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to my Project1.exe, with a value of 9999, and the same for the key in the `Wow6432Node`, for the 64-bit stuff.

I have also checked the Useragent against [www.WhatsMyUserAgent.com](http://www.WhatsMyUserAgent.com), and it says I am running MSIE9.0

Anything else I need to do?

**EDIT - FIXED:** - Apparently I need the following Metatag in my document:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: Aw, screw me - I needed the metatag.. I hate when this happens, I type up a question after tons of research, and 2 minutes later I find the solution..

Comment: So put the solution in the "answer" section so it helps other people, too.

Comment: And accept it. We don't frown on that, in fact it is encouraged by Jeff Atwood himself.

Comment: @Rob - I'm afraid to do that, as almost everytime I did that, I got downvoted..

Comment: Then people should read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Lars @Rob @Marjan - Done, hope this will do.

Comment: Nice research, and nice answer jeff, upvoted both your question and your answer because it's useful for anybody who needs to know about any IE9 specific HTML features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was that **my** HTML code (see OP) did not include the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

By doing this, you can avoid having to modify the Registry, as the above forces the Webbrowser to render in IE9 Standards mode. The TWebbrowser component by default is set to IE7.

I tested this by doing the above with and without the registry modification, and it worked since I have IE9 installed.

Of course, you can only ensure that the above code is present if you create the document yourself, or find some sneaky way of injecting it into the document. If you want CSS3 stuff working on 3rd party websites, then you need the registry key (unless of course they have the above code in their document).

This is the registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/FeatureControl/FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`. Add a DWORD key, and name it YOURAPPNAME.exe (in my case, Project1.exe). Set the value to one of the following:

```
9999 (0x270F):  Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
9000 (0x2328):  Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
8888 (0x22B8):  Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
8000 (0x1F40):  Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.
7000 (0x1B58):  Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.
```

(From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Since I want to force IE9 Standards, my Regedit window will look like this:

[image: Example]

By doing that, you are telling the Webbrowser inside your app that you want to use IE9 Standards (CSS3 and HTML5 stuff). **Now**, the code in my OP will **still** not work, even though we just did this. Why? Because I was missing a `doctype`. By adding a doctype, the border radius property worked.

Hope this is helpful to whoever else faces the same issue.

Comment: @Marjan - Lets just hope someone can use it (and even better: understand what I mean :P )